# Hibernate Session / JPA EntityManager syncronization between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, synchronization

I know well that Hibernate `Session` and the `EntityManager` are not thread-safe, and thus I should not share entities between threads. But sometimes it may happen, by accident or negligence.
This may (and had, in production) lead to race conditions, for example it may throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if the `EntityManager` is being used by another thread during the `close()` in the "owner" thread (the one who originally created it).
It's not only the use of the `EntityManager` directly, but also any (not detached) entities that may trigger a LazyLoading.

As said before, the fix is to not use entities in other threads, but sometime this may not be possible or even known.
So I've come up with a way to "synchronize" the session between threads, so no other thread can access the session until the owner one closes it.

https://github.com/lelmarir/hibernate-session-synchronizer

Simply put, I create a `ReentrantLock` when the `Session` get created and acquire it (for the owner thread), then acquire it again before any call (using a proxy), so only the "owner" will be able to get it and all others will wait, until the lock get released at the closing of the session and all other waiting threads can step in.

This way I can avoid any race-conditions (trading them for a possible deadlock) and detect and fix them later.

Is this approach viable? Do you see any major problem?

Comment: I didn't check out your code too deeply, but I think the easiest approach would be to create a `SessionImpl` subclass that has `synchronized` on all public methods.

Comment: Thanks Christian, you may be right, it might be enough, but since the session should not be used between threads, I've used a lock to disallow any concurrent access from others than the owning thread